# how ansible connects to remote devices

Tags: python, networking, ssh, automation, ansible

I am learning how to create ansible modules in python, I want to connect to remote devices, I am looking at ansible source code to see how they connect, but I still cant understand how???

I took this simple module file from ansible to check how they connect to the remote device and do all the stuff that the module does
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/ping.py

I don't see any socket or libraries for ssh in this file, so how does it happed?

does ansible first connect to the remote host and then activate the module on the remote host?

is that why it requires python on remote devices?

I cant really understand it

Comment: We use ansible cli tool to run adhoc commands and ansible-playbook to copy and execute the required modules as per the playbook tasks. Its basically these cli tools which connect to the remote hosts as per the inventory and copy the required modules and execute them on remote host as per my understanding. As mentioned in the ansible docs we need to make sure we can ssh to remote host before we can manage the remote host.

Comment: Oversimplified view: the module is archived to a tarball file on the controller. That file is pushed to the remote host using [whatever connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html) is configured for the host (ssh, local, docker...). The tarball is extracted to a temporary dir on the target and executed with python. The result is returned back to the controller. The temporary content is cleaned-up. -- You might get a better understanding running ansible(-playbook) with `-vvv`

Answer (score 0):

You basically got it, below is the description from the Ansible modules docs. Hence, why it needs python for the remote and you can pick which interpreter.

The connection type isn't part of the module, those are via the connection plugins (extend Ansible core functionality).

> **Modules**
>
> *The code or binaries that Ansible copies to and executes on each
> managed node (when needed) to accomplish the action defined in each
> Task.* Each module has a particular use, from administering users on a
> specific type of database to managing VLAN interfaces on a specific
> type of network device. You can invoke a single module with a task, or
> invoke several different modules in a playbook. Ansible modules are
> grouped in collections. For an idea of how many collections Ansible
> includes, see the Collection Index.
>
> **Plugins**
>
> *Pieces of code that expand Ansible’s core capabilities, they can
> control how you connect to a managed node (connection plugins)*,
> manipulate data (filter plugins) and even control what is displayed in
> the console (callback plugins). See Working with plugins for details.

[Ansible Modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/basic_concepts.html#modules)
[Ansible Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/basic_concepts.html#plugins)

Answer (score -2):

As far as i know, Ansible use ssh to connect.

You can perform a research whith 'repo:ansible/ansible filename:ssh' in
github research [here](https://github.com/search?l=&p=1&q=repo%3Aansible%2Fansible%20filename%3Assh&type=Code)

You can examin this [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/d23226a6f4737fb17b7b1be0d09f39e249832c7f/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py).
Ansible also use the lib paramiko to connect with ssh.
as we can see [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/2cbfd1e350cbe1ca195d33306b5a9628667ddda8/lib/ansible/utils/ssh_functions.py)

Comment: Ansible uses a [connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html) to reach the target host. Ssh is indeed the most common but there are others: local, docker, winrm... You can even write your own.

Comment: yes, it use 2 methods:

 - ansible-builtin-ssh-connect-via-ssh-client-binary
 - paramiko_ssh

Ansible doesn't need agent on target but a ssh server.
So my understanding is that you can use both on the same machine (client and server)

Comment: `local`, `docker` or `winrm` do not use ssh at all.